# Reading grib2 format data without pygrib package

Tags: python, python-2.7, netcdf, grib

I'm familiar with reading and extracting information on **grib2** format meteorology data with the python package `pygrib`. It's easy to implement.

I have tried to install the **pygrib** package in Linux cluster using `conda install`.

But when I import this package, the error comes with follow information:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>   ImportError: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.7' not found (required by /home/hyf/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/../../libgrib_api.so)

I could't update the glibc version to 2.7 due to the privilege limits. I have tried to compile the glibc-2.7 manually but causing terrible **Segmentation faults**.

Is there any alternative method to read grib2 data without the support of **pygrib**.

Any comments and advice would be appreciate!

Comment: Have you tried [pynio](https://www.pyngl.ucar.edu/Nio.shtml)?  You can use it directly or through the [xarray](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/index.html) package.

Comment: I've been able to install pygrib in anaconda, but I had to try different order of package install, so yes it is problematic. For reading GRIB2 from python you can also use grib_api from ECMWF, it is very powerful https://software.ecmwf.int/wiki/display/GRIB/Home

Comment: You can try with solution: convert grib2 to netcdf and then use netCDF4 library to extract information.

Answer (score 4):

If you can read netcdf and don't mind relying on an external program, you should be able to convert grib2 to netcdf with [wgrib2](http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/wesley/wgrib2/):

```
wgrib2 grib2_file.grb2 -netcdf netcdf_file.nc
```